# throw custom exception collect info and throw again

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

my project requirement to parse the files in given directory. I created classes like MyDirectory, MyFiles, MyRecords and MyFields....it's basically in-memory representation of my data. I need help in exception handling. I want to log exception and also to display error on screen. If exception occur at MyFields class level I want to add field name to CustomErrorString, throw exception to MyRecords class. catch that exception in MyRecords class append Record number to CustomErrorString, throw same exception to MyFiles class. catch exception in MyFiles class append File Name to CustomErrorString etc...can anyone of you tell me how to create custom exception handling class for this and how to handle it in various classes and also handle general system.Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom exceptions.  For example, something as simple as this:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public MyException(string message, string someProperty, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
        SomeProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

When catching any exception, you can then *wrap* that exception in your custom one, setting the original as the inner exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new MyException("Custom error message", "Custom info", ex);
}
```

You can also do anything else you like in that `catch` block, of course.  Log information, etc.  And you can design your custom exception and its constructors however you like.

The main point here is that you retain the original exception, unmodified, as a property on the new exception.  Each layer in the stack which wants to add information to the exception should do so by wrapping it in an exception of its own, which can have any custom properties you like.

Comment: Thanks David. Can you elaborate your last paragraph. how can i retain value of original exception? Do I need to create something like public static StringBuilder MyCustomError varible in MyException class and keep appending string to it  as i catch it on called function?

Comment: @bansi: Setting the original exception as the `.InnerException` property (which is what the `base()` constructor used in this example does) will retain that original exception.  So, for example, if you do this 3 times in the stack then you'll have a total of 4 exceptions, each of which is a property on another.